# My anonymous pipe is accessible by other processes

Tags: python, linux, pipe

according to [this blog post](https://ofstack.com/python/14291/an-example-of-an-anonymous-pipe-for-python-process-communication.html) os.pipe is used to create anonymous pipes.

first python console:

```py
import os
rfd, wfd = os.pipe()
w = os.fdopen(wfd, 'bw')
w.write(b'1\n')  # 2
w.flush()
os.getpid()  # 13134
rfd  # 3
```

second python console:

```py
pipe = open('/proc/13134/fd/3', 'rb')
pipe.readline()  # b'1\n'
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156870/227331 also mentions this problem. How can I create a pipe that is not accessible by any process?

Comment: That same answer also says that any file descriptor is accessible through `/proc` and describes why that's not a problem.

Comment: ups yea. Doesn't that defeat the purpose of it? I changed the question text

Comment: so what am I supposed to do? Is it just impossible to hand information from root processes over to non-root clients without anybody being able to sniff that stuff?

Comment: Only the process owner and root can use /proc/*/fd/, not "anybody".

Comment: From the link `The "peeker" must be either running under the same user as the subject or root, so it's not a security problem`. Use another user. Btw, you can create a pipe, open it and remove it, so that _the pipe_ is not accessible. But the file descriptor will be accessible from `/proc`. You can also unmount `/proc`. Run the process in chroot.

Comment: I can't, because wayland doesn't permit running GUIs as other users

Comment: But... why is this a bad thing? Don't you trust the user of the computer? He can do whatever he wants with the computer anyway, why you care if reads from one fd? Still - `wayland doesn't permit running GUIs as other users` - so run two processes, one for gui and one for fd.

Comment: Because it contains keystrokes and wayland is designed to make keyloggers harder for a reason probably, so I won't design my application to circumvent that.

Comment: I'm upvoting your question because it's well written. It is to the point, with code showing what you mean, and you have done your research. Though there is a bit of ranting in your comments, which may or may not provoke people to downvote. You should probably mention the scope in the question, not in comments. If root, Wayland, and GUI are crucial, put that in the question. Comments can be hard to read; they are ordered by votes, not choronologically.  Also explain better why you're concerned if that `/proc` entry is only readable to the owner and root anyway.

Comment: I'm not too sure about it, but if you passed an fd from a process with a different uid, via an AF_UNIX socket, I think you would end up with an fd that is open in the process, but can't be opened by another unprivileged process. This should also be true for inherited file descriptors.